# Should i move my erc20 token from ropsten to main network?

Tags: tokens, ether, erc-20, ropsten

I have just created token in ROPSTEN network, so Im confused now... Can I use my tokens in main ether network (sel, give, etc) or I just van play with them in test network and forget...?

**Should i move my erc20 token to main network?** to use my tokens as coins in regular ether network?

Answer (score 1):

Ropsten is, well, a testnet. It can be used for testing various blockchain functionalities but everything in Ropsten is useless in the "real" world. You can't use Ropsten assets in the main chain and all assets in Ropsten are worthless.

So if you want your assets to have some real users, real usage and possibly read value you should put it into the mainnet. Just make sure it works and you've tested it fully first in Ropsten.

Comment: Thank for info! But How to "put it into the mainnet."? It si possible ti tranfer tokens from ropsten to "Real world"? Or I must create new token only (in main net)

Comment: Thank for info! But How to "put it into the mainnet."? It is possible to transfer tokens from ropsten to "Real world"? Or I can/must create new token only (to the mainnet), and there are no option to move all tokents to the man net. Example tokens: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xbd2944e34912cc43f81870c534ccf711cc80c2ba

Comment: there's no way to explicitly transfer anything. You just need to create the same token contract in mainnet. There wouldn't be any point in transferring the ownerships anyway as the owner addresses would be possibly different in the mainnet. So just create a new contract and start distributing the tokens in whatever way you want.